# Search within a spreadsheet a cell, and change another

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a script in google sheets. What I'm trying to do is to search the value of a cell (let's say A2 sheet1), then change the value of another cell (B2 sheet2). When the first iteration is over, proceed to the next row (A3 sheet1) and again change the value of B2. Also wait 10 secs at the end of every iteration.

I don't know why it is not working. After I run the code it just says "Finished", but nothing has changed.

```js
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var gensheet = ss.getSheetByName('Generador SE');
  var clientsheet = ss.getSheetByName('Clientes SE');
  
  var clientrange = clientsheet.getRange("A1:C200");
  var clientsquantity = clientrange.getNumRows()
  var servicetochange = gensheet.getRange(2,2)
  
  var i;
  for (i=1;i>clientsquantity;i++){
  
    var currentservice = clientrange.getRange(i,1).getValue;
    servicetochange=gensheet.getRange().setValue(currentservice);
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
  
  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed some code in the loop ... now it does something (but I can't be sure it does what you expect):

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  var gensheet = ss.getSheetByName('Generador SE');
  var clientsheet = ss.getSheetByName('Clientes SE');

  var clientrange = clientsheet.getRange("A1:C200");
  var clientsquantity = clientrange.getNumRows()
  var servicetochange = gensheet.getRange(2,2)

  var i;
  for (i=1;i<clientsquantity;i++){

    var currentservice = clientrange.offset(i,0,1,1).getValue();
    servicetochange.offset(i,0,1,1).setValue(currentservice);
    Utilities.sleep(10000);

  }

}
```